# Windows 10 mapping drive using cmd / .bat

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, network-shares, mapped-drive

I am trying to map a hard drive using cmd but it seems not to save the credentials. In the long game I want to create a .bat that maps the drive, provides the credentials, and saves them so less technical users can just double click the bat.

What am I doing wrong?

```
net use Z: \\XX.XX.XX.XX\SharesFolder /u:XX.XX.XX.XX\username password /p:yes
```

When I tried to add /savecred it says it is conflicting switches. When I use it alone it says that I can't access this shared folder because my organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access.

Please help :(

/Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of command (simple networking connection and not Active Directory), you need to enter the credentials each time. This is entirely normal.  Command shell processing is different than Network Browsing (which is more integrated into Windows Security)

If you desire, you can put the password to the device in the batch file line. But then you need to be certain about the security of the computer and person using it.

Make sure your organization is aware of what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The thing is that one can manually map the drive with exact same information and it works, only through cmd it doesn't. How do I do it with the batch file?

Comment: Command processing is different than network browsing so it needs credentials each time. As noted, that is normal.

Comment: @John sorry to say it, but thats not true. If you enter the correct command it will work and it will remember the credentials each time. It is more likely something else is going wrong. For example, you cannot connect to a network share with different credentials if other credentials are stored too.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide setups for that. Command processing on our computers require credentials every time. If Network Browsing is available, then credentials will be remembered for this. We may be using different setups.

Comment: If the users have an AD connection on a Server, then command mapping will not require a password having been mapped once. I forgot about this since the question was about mapping a disk and did not appear to involve AD (as I read the question)